# How to disable BitLocker recovery password with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot

I am using Dell XPS 13 9360 after I installed the latest version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I noticed that every single boot in windows 10 the BitLocker recovery ask me to put the password! any idea how to fix or disable this issue?

Comment: Doesn't BitLocker require the Recovery Password always after a hardware change or BIOS/UEFI setup change? Maybe also after the bootloader changed? If you changed anything in the UEFI settings, try and revert that. If that doesn't help, you'd probably have to get the Recovery Password... But I might be wrong, didn't have to use BitLocker for too long or interacted very much with it.

Comment: If using SSD see this: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/11/05/busted_ssd_encryption/